# Fix bookmarks in foxit reader (or suggest alternative reader)

Tags: pdf

I have until now been using an old version of Foxit reader (8.3.X), which by default allowed you to position your bookmarks within the page, so that when you click them you go to a specific location in that page.

I have just installed a new version (11.X) and even (10.X) which creates bookmarks as references to a page (not to a position with a page), making the feature almost useless for what I need. Is this simply a setting problem i.e. is there a way to make bookmarks in the new Foxit readers behave as they should?

This does specifically regard to bookmarks I am creating in an otherwise unbookmarked book. When opening a book in which I created bookmarks in the old software, those bookmarks do work properly in the new software, so it seems to be a problem with the creation of bookmarks in the new software.

Alternatively, can someone suggest a free (or cheap) pdf reader which allows you to create bookmarks properly?

Comment: https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 1):

It turns out to have a just slightly akward workaround. Right clicking a bookmark you can change its view to custom and only then will it store the information about where to go. The good news is that when creating new bookmarks by right clicking an existing one, new ones will inherit this custom mode. The bad news is that they still wont generally store the right position for bookmarks so its a two step process of create a bookmark then set the destination.